# Pfsense upstream gateway how it works?

Tags: openvpn, pfsense

I have 2 pfsense firewall setup in my office with 2 ISP, the primary firewall is connected to both ISP-1 AND ISP-2 and the secondary firewall that has OpenVPN setup is only connected to ISP-2. now when I try to use the openvpn client that is connected to the secondary firewall I can't able to ping the  Primary firewall and other LAN devices that are connected to it. but when I configure the upstream gateway in my secondary firewall by adding the default gateway IP of my primary. now im able to ping all devices using openvpn client.

I just want to ask if this is the bestway to do it. event if my objective setup works.

Please check my topology setup.
[image: this is my topology Diagram that has upstream gateway]